# How Can I Import An Image and Maintain Proportions

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I'm making a photo editing iPhone application where I require importing an image into the app, but I want to do this without losing **any** image quality or resolution. I've been researching quite a lot on google and other websites on this issue, but I haven't found the right answer. How can I import an image and maintain proportions, but also scale the image so that it can easily be edited, and saved later on with the same quality?

Comment: Where are you importing from - the cloud, a web service, photo library?  That's a separate question.   You can *display* correct porportions setting the UIView.contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Comment: I'm importing the image from the photo library. The problem with that is that when I edit the image I use the CGContext which displays a UIImage but does not scale it down.